# RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND in Paypal

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, paypal

I have to setup paypal for payment in my ReactJs Project. Inorder to that i create paypal button and Call PayPal to get the transaction details. It seems it works well and i got success message with transaction details also.And the problem arise here is when i try to Validate the transaction details are as expected in my server side ie, nodejs (as mention here: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/")i got this Error. In my nodjs project i am using "**@paypal/checkout-server-sdk**".

My code is:

in ReactJs:
PaypalButton.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const PaypalButton = props => {
const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);

const addPaypalSdk = () => {
const clientID ="**********CLIENT_ID**************";
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientID}`;
script.async = true;
script.onload = () => {
  setSdkReady(true);
};
script.onerror = () => {
  throw new Error("Paypal SDK could not be loaded.");
};

document.body.appendChild(script);
};

useEffect(() => {
if (window !== undefined && window.paypal === undefined) {
  addPaypalSdk();
} else if (
  window !== undefined &&
  window.paypal !== undefined &&
  props.onButtonReady
) {
  props.onButtonReady();
}
}, []);

//amount goes in the value field we will use props of the button for this
const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
console.log("createOrder", data);
return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units: [
    {
      amount: {
        currency_code: "USD",
        value: props.amount
      }
    }
  ]
});
};

const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
return actions.order
  .capture()
  .then(details => {
    if (props.onSuccess) {
      window.alert("Payment Sucessfull...");
      return props.onSuccess(data, details);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  };

 const clickPaypal = flag => {
    return props.onClick(flag);
 };

if (!sdkReady && window.paypal === undefined) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

const Button = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", {
React,
ReactDOM
});

return (
  <div style={{ width: 200 }}>
  <Button
    {...props}
    createOrder={
      props.amount && !createOrder
        ? (data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)
        : (data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)
    }
    onApprove={
      props.onSuccess
        ? (data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)
        : (data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)
    }
    style={{
      layout: "horizontal",
      color: "gold",
      shape: "pill",
      label: "pay",
      size: "responsive",
      tagline: true
    }}
    onClick={props.onClick ? clickPaypal : clickPaypal}
  />
</div>
);
};
export default PaypalButton;

Pay.js

onSuccess = (payment, details) => {
const {
  processInvoicePaypalPayment
} = this.props;

this.paypalSucesssDetails = { ...details };

processInvoicePaypalPayment( .     //call to server
  {
    invoice: invoice.data._id,
    orderId: this.paypalSucesssDetails.id // This order id is from sucess transaction details
  },
  this.paypalCapture
);
};

render=()=>{
   <PaypalButton
    amount={invoiceData.amount}
    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
    env={"sandbox"}
    onClick={this.clickPaypal}
   />
}
```

and in my nodejs

```
 import paypal from "@paypal/checkout-server-sdk";
      const clientId = "CLIENTID";
      const clientSecret = "SECRET";
      const environment = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
      const client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);

      try{
      export const processInvoicePaypalPayment = async (user, data) => {
             const customerId = user.customer,
             { invoice: invoiceId, orderId: orderID } = data;

             let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);
       const createOrder = async () => {
       const response = await client.execute(request);

       return { ok: true, data: { _id: invoiceId, payment: response.result } };

       };

       const result = await createOrder();

       }
       }catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
       }
```

And the result is:

```
  { Error: {"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","details": 
  [{"location":"path","issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],"message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"c3b5026d6dd74","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

How can i solve this issue? Any help and Suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a sample orderID you are looking up? Can you print and share a sample of the actual request text/json ?

Comment: My sample orderId is "6VG34423VV633792H".     and the  successdetails is create_time: "2020-03-05T09:56:39Z"
​
id: "6VG34423VV633792H"
​
intent: "CAPTURE"
​
links: Array [ {…} ]
​
payer: Object { email_address: "name@gmail.com", payer_id: "3LNXV55Q55GHE", address: {…}, … }
​
purchase_units: Array [ {…} ]
​
status: "COMPLETED"
​
update_time: "2020-03-05T09:57:09Z"

Comment: `6VG34423VV633792H` does not appear to be a valid sandbox orderID. Where are you getting this value from?

Comment: return actions.order
      .capture()
      .then(details => {--------------> from this details
        if (props.onSuccess) {
          window.alert("Payment Sucessfull...");
          return props.onSuccess(data, details);
        }
      })

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that you have a client-side integration for processing the transaction, and then you are attempting to use a server-side API call to check the order status, but that server-side API call is not compatible with the order processing that you used.

You have two options:

1. Switch to a server-side API call on the *payment ID*, not the order ID. This is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get. A payment ID is more useful than an order ID anyway, since the payment/transaction ID is what is actually persisted for years in www.paypal.com and used for accounting purposes.  The order ID is only used during payment approval.
2. Switch to a server-side integration pattern, like this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  Then you will be doing your own API calls to set up and capture the payment, and your existing OrdersGetRequest(..) can work

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you mention i tried the first one but i haven't payment Id. Because it is null. Dont know why. and i started to implement second one ie, server side implemetation. inorder to that in my createOrder                                   const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
    const clientID ="CLIENTID";
    return fetch(`https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientID}`, {
      method: "post"
    })
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        return data.orderID;
      });
  };

Comment: THEN I GOT Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). where i went wrong?

Comment: The full response of a successful order capture should include a payment ID somewhere, which will be different from an order ID, and not null.  A server-side implementation requires actual endpoints on your server that implement the API calls, which you fetch().  You don't fetch the PayPal SDK js, that makes no sense.